# Does Azure WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE really mean don't unpack the zip archive?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service

I'm doing a zip deploy of a .NET Framework web app to an Azure App Service via a GitHub workflow.

I have set `WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE` to 1 in the Azure console's `Settings / Configuration / Application settings` page.  I've also tried setting `WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_ZIP` to 1 there just in case (although I think this is an obsolete flag).

The package is building correctly in GitHub and I can see it showing up in my Kudu debug console, under `C:\home\site\wwwroot` (as MyPackageName.zip) as well as in `C:\home\data\SitePackages` (as 20220512205318.zip, for example).

The deploy portion of my YAML is:

```
deploy:
  runs-on: windows-latest
  needs: build
  environment:
    name: 'Test'
    url: ${{ steps.deploy-to-webapp.outputs.webapp-url }}

  steps:
    - name: Download artifact from build job
      uses: actions/download-artifact@v2
      with:
        name: ASP-app

    - name: Deploy to Azure Web App
      id: deploy-to-webapp
      uses: azure/webapps-deploy@v2
      with:
        app-name: ${{ env.AZURE_WEBAPP_NAME }}
        publish-profile: ${{ secrets.AZUREAPPSERVICE_PUBLISHPROFILE_XYZsecret }}
        package: .
```

And the .PublishSettings I've uploaded to GitHub looks like:

```
<publishData>
    <!-- Which one of these 3 profiles is my YAML using?  I don't actually know. -->
    <publishProfile profileName="mywebappname-test - Web Deploy" publishMethod="MSDeploy"  etc="foobar">
        <databases/>
    </publishProfile>
    <publishProfile profileName="mywebappname-test - FTP" publishMethod="FTP" etc="foobar">
        <databases/>
    </publishProfile>
    <publishProfile profileName="mywebappname-test - Zip Deploy" publishMethod="ZipDeploy" etc="foobar">
        <databases/>
    </publishProfile>
</publishData>
```

The zip package is *not* getting automatically unpacked. The MSFT support rep I talked to suggested that this was the problem, and indeed when I download the package to my machine and drop it into Kudu's `Tools/Zip Push Deploy` page, I see that the package is unpacked, and I can get the site to work by setting the appropriate Physical Path to match the '/' Virtual path.  Specifically the Kudu Tools Zip Push causes my web.config and favicon.ico etc. files to show up in:

```
C:\home\site\wwwroot\Content\D_C\a\foo\bar\good\boy\obj\Test\Package\PackageTmp
```

and I can go to the Azure console for my app service, navigate to `Settings / Configuration/ Path Mappings, Virtual applications and directories`, and edit the existing entry to:

```
Virtual path: /
Physical Path: site\wwwroot\Content\D_C\a\foo\bar\good\boy\obj\Test\Package\PackageTmp
Type: Application
```

and then see my site come up in a browser.

However, when *don't* do anything to unpack the archive, and I leave the entry as:

```
Virtual path: /
Physical Path: site\wwwroot
Type: Application
```

I can't see my site in a browser and instead just see "You do not have permission to view this directory or page."  When I then dig in to the logs in Kudo, I see 403.14 - Forbidden errors on my main site and a 404.0 - Not Found error on C:\home\site\wwwroot\favicon.ico.  (Like the rest of my files, favicon.ico is still inside the zip archive at `[...]\foo\bar\good\boy\obj\Test\Package\PackageTmp\favicon.ico`.)

My questions are:

1. Should my web app be able to run at all with just my zip file sitting there as `C:\home\site\wwwroot\MyPackageName.zip?`  Or does it really need to be unpacked as the MSFT rep indicated?
2. If it is supposed to run this way, any ideas on what am I missing?  I assume it's something in my YAML (which of the 3 publishProfile settings is it actually choosing here?) or in `Settings / Configuration/ Path Mappings` or `Application settings`, but I have no idea what at this point and I'm running out of ideas.

Thanks, Eric

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. > Should my web app be able to run at all with just my zip file sitting there as C:\home\site\wwwroot\MyPackageName.zip?

Pretty much, yes, just not in wwwroot. When WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE is enabled, the application is run from the archive directly as a read only directory mount. Nothing is copied to wwwwroot or anywhere else.

2. > If it is supposed to run this way, any ideas on what am I missing?

My understanding is package deploy from GitHub is not supported or rather GitHub archives are incompatible with run from package on App Service.

Comment: Thanks @dwellman, and yikes. Are you referring to the issue described at https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/10240 and https://github.com/fnbk/world/blob/master/README.md?

Comment: @Eric Hirst I am referring to this document https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-run-package#create-a-project-zip-package

"you cannot deploy that file as-is. GitHub adds additional nested directories, which do not work with App Service."

Comment: thanks, I see that now.  Yes, the packages getting created bury the actual application deep inside a folder structure (... foo\bar\good\boy\obj ... in my description).  This is the same folder structure I get when I run msbuild locally with the /p:PublishProfile=AzureCI.pubxml option, and there *is* an archive.xml index near the root of the structure, but apparently App Service doesn't understand it.

Answer (score 1):

dwellman's response was the correct answer to my original question, but I'll add some more detail here on how I used this information to get my deployment to work properly. I feel like the inability to read the zip archive's internal index XML file(s) to find the correct relative path is an Azure flaw, but until it's addressed, I hope others may find this useful.

My first step was to abandon the idea of deploying as a zip file.  It's possible I could have still made this work by doing some post-processing to zip things up in a different format without the nested folders, but I decided in my case that the benefits of a single-file deployment weren't worth the cost. To stop deploying as a zip file, I manually edited the .pubxml file I was passing in as msbuild option `/p:PublishProfile=AzureCI.pubxml`.  The changes I made were to change `PackageAsSingleFile` from true to false, and change `DesktopBuildPackageLocation` from a zip file path to a folder path.

This alone was enough to get my site to get deployed to Azure as individual files instead of a zip archive. The files were still buried in an ugly folder structure, but I could at least see them in Kudu and get the site to work by applying the same `Settings / Configuration/ Path Mappings, Virtual applications and directories` adjustment I describe in my original question.

I could have stopped there, but I wanted to be able to just use the default virtual path and not have my Azure configuration be so dependent on my upstream processes. In other words, I wanted to just have my web.config and favicon.ico etc land directly in `C:\home\site\wwwroot` instead of deep in the weeds of a subfolder structure. To make this work, I changed the package argument to webapps-deploy in my YAML from . to the appropriate path as follows:

```
- name: Deploy to Azure Web App
  id: deploy-to-webapp
  uses: azure/webapps-deploy@v2
  with:
    app-name: ${{ env.AZURE_WEBAPP_NAME }}
    publish-profile: ${{ secrets.AZUREAPPSERVICE_PUBLISHPROFILE_XYZsecret }}
    package: .\Archive\Content\D_C\a\foo\bar\good\boy\obj\Test\Package\PackageTmp
```

This caused the deployment process to pick off just the files I needed from the build and drop them into `C:\home\site\wwwroot`. I could then revert the path mapping kludge and be on my way.