# Azure App Service application won't start

Tags: azure-web-app-service, azure-pipelines

I am deploying a .Net 6 app to an Azure App Service running on Linux.  The deploy is successful but the app won't load.  I see the following errors in the log:

```
/2023_09_19_lw0sdlwk0005GK_default_docker.log)
2023-09-19T20:36:40.414001691Z       The application 'Change Management.dll' does not exist.
2023-09-19T20:36:40.414006391Z   * You intended to execute a .NET SDK command:
2023-09-19T20:36:40.414010091Z       No .NET SDKs were found.
2023-09-19T20:36:40.414013791Z
2023-09-19T20:36:40.414017291Z Download a .NET SDK:
2023-09-19T20:36:40.414020891Z https://aka.ms/dotnet-download
2023-09-19T20:36:40.414024491Z
2023-09-19T20:36:40.414027891Z Learn about SDK resolution:
2023-09-19T20:36:40.414031391Z https://aka.ms/dotnet/sdk-not-found
```

I think its not finding the dll, rather than a .Net error, since its Microsoft's container. I'm trying to run it from a zip file and I see the file in the right place:

```
kudu_ssh_user@xxxxxxxxxab:/$ dir data/SitePackages/
20230919184359.zip  20230919191243.zip  packagename.txt
```

The app service is supposed to find that zip and mount it to run the app.  I did add an Environment Variable `WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE=1`

In case it helps, here is my yaml file

```
trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

variables:
  solution: '**/*.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'

steps:
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@1

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  inputs:
    command: 'restore'
    restoreSolution: '**/*.sln'
    feedsToUse: 'config'
    nugetConfigPath: nuget.config

- task: VSBuild@1
  inputs:
    solution: '$(solution)'
    msbuildArgs: '/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:Pa ckageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:PackageLocation="$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)" /p:UseWPP_CopyWebApplication=true  /p:OutDir="$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)"'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'  
    
- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'
    ArtifactName: 'drop'
    publishLocation: 'Container'  

- task: AzureWebApp@1
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: 'Subscription Name'
    appType: 'webAppLinux'
    appName: 'myapp'
    resourceGroupName: 'Group Name'
    deploymentMethod: zipDeploy
    startUpCommand: 'dotnet " Change Management.dll"'
    package: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/**/*.zip'
```

Any suggestions?

**Update:**
I implemented the yaml file structure suggested and I get the exact same result as I did before.  I'm pretty sure the root cause is the container is not finding the project dll where it expects it.  I checked the pipeline artifact and the zip file contains all the dll's are in the top level and there is a `wwwroot` folder with the `.css`, etc.  I looked at the app service folders and everything is buried under `site/wwwroot/Content/D_C/a/1/s/HR\ Taxonomy\ Change\ Management/obj/Release/net6.0/PubTmp/Out/`.  I know the zip deploy is supposed to mount the zip contents but does that mean it should be extracted to the site folder?  I'm still researching that here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-run-package

**Update #2**
I tried a standard web deploy to 'site/wwwroot' by changing the deploy step to `deploymentMethod: 'zipDeploy'`.  This loaded all the dlls in the 'site/wwwroot' folder and there is a wwwroot subfolder which contains my css files.  The site now loads but none of the css is loaded.  In the browser inspector, I'm getting a 404 error for all the css files. I don't like the two wwwroot folders...

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***I have used the below YAML pipeline to deploy dotnet 6.0 Web app into Azure Web app and it deployed and ran successfully like below:-***

*Make sure you use **UseDotNet@2 task** to install .net sdk and deploy your web app like below:-*

```yaml
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
      - main

jobs:
- job: Build
  displayName: 'Build and Publish'
  pool:
    vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'
  steps:
  - task: UseDotNet@2
    displayName: 'Install .NET Core SDK'
    inputs:
      version: '6.x'

  - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
    displayName: 'Restore Dependencies'
    inputs:
      command: 'restore'
      projects: '**/*.csproj'

  - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
    displayName: 'Build Project'
    inputs:
      command: 'build'
      projects: '**/*.csproj'
      arguments: '--configuration Release'

  - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
    displayName: 'Publish Project'
    inputs:
      command: 'publish'
      projects: '**/*.csproj'
      publishWebProjects: true
      arguments: '--configuration Release --output $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
      zipAfterPublish: true

  - task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
    displayName: 'Publish Artifact'
    inputs:
      targetPath: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
      artifactName: 'publishedApp'
      publishLocation: 'pipeline'

- job: Deploy
  displayName: 'Deploy to Azure Web App'
  dependsOn: Build
  pool:
    vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'
  steps:
  - download: current
    artifact: 'publishedApp'

  - task: UseDotNet@2
    displayName: 'Install .NET Core SDK'
    inputs:
      version: '6.x'

  - task: AzureWebApp@1
    displayName: 'Azure Web App Deploy'
    inputs:
      azureSubscription: 'xxx subscription (xxxx-xxx8-44d6-xxx-xxxx)'
      appType: 'webApp'
      appName: 'siliconwebapp09'
      package: '$(Agent.BuildDirectory)/**/*.zip'
      deploymentMethod: 'auto'
```

**Output:-**

[image]

[image]

All files deployed successfully in wwwroot like below:-

[image]

Comment: I worked on implementing your yaml steps and finally got it to work at end of day.  It works fine but leaves me in the same place as my yaml steps did.  It deploys a zip file but the container won't start the app.  Can you share your App Service Environment Variables?  (excluding secrets).  Maybe I'm missing something there.

Comment: Can you check the log stream while loading your web app in the browser and check what exactly is the error? Like here- https://i.imgur.com/7sG0ouP.png

Comment: I directly used the above yaml code and did not use any additional secrets.. It worked with the steps above..

Comment: The error is in my original post.

Comment: This is an interesting discussion of path mapping for zip deployments. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72222698/does-azure-website-run-from-package-really-mean-dont-unpack-the-zip-archive   Except his main issue is deploying from GitHub which is a known issue app service.

Comment: I'm going to mark this as answered,  based on the original question and open a new one for css.